# python regex don't recognize pattern

Tags: python, regex

start by saying that I've already read the python documentation about regex expression, I cannot manage to rewrite my regex in order to be used with python *re* module.
So, it is a basic regex:

```
\_*([A-Z][A-Z]+\_*[A-Z|0-9|\_]*)+\_*
```

I know that is ok for my purpose because with egrep it matches perfectly what I want, but python continues return None for each analyzed string.

**EDIT**
expected output is everything starting with or without _, it is all uppercase, starting with letter and after could be possibly letters or digits, also _: XXX, XX_X, _XXX,_XX_XXXX_ XX_
where input is a string with lowercase letters and spaces.

Comment: Add the strings that you think it should and should not match

Comment: whats the input string for matching regex? what's the expected output?

Comment: The `[A-Z|0-9|\_]` is suspect: Alteration does not work in a character class. It matches a SINGLE character inside the `[]` only

Comment: You don't need to escape `_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your regex can be improve, I can suggest you something more like `_?[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]+`

As rugie said, you don't need to escape the `_`, and `[A-Z|0-9|\_]` will not really work as you want (see dawg's comment).

Secondary, which function of the re module did you use? If it's `re.match`, it will probably not work since `re.match` search from the beginning of the string.
Do you want to know if your pattern is in the string, or catch all the patterns in this string? You can use `re.search` for the first, and `re.findall` for the 2nd one.

Tell us what you have tried, and we will be able to help you more.

Comment: I've managed to use findall and rewrite a better (pythonic) regex, and now I am able to find what I am looking for! thank you Liad!

Comment: Glad to know :)